# How does Harry get to platform nine and three quarters?

Tags: harry-potter

In chapter 6 of *Harry Potter* how does Harry get to platform nine and three quarters? How does he figure out how to get there?

Comment: Is your question how he got to the train station, or how he got onto the secret platform once in the train station?

Answer (score 7):

He got lift to the King's Cross Station with Dursleys’ car.

> ”They reached King’s Cross at half past ten. Uncle Vernon dumped Harry’s trunk on to a trolley and wheeled it into the station for him. Harry thought this was strangely kind until Uncle Vernon stopped dead, facing the platforms with a nasty grin on his face.”
>   “Well, there you are, boy. Platform nine — platform ten. Your
>   platform should be somewhere in the middle, but they don’t seem
>   to have built it yet, do they?” – HP 1 cp.6 p.90

When he had been a while between platform 10 and 9, he heard Weasley’ family and asked them how to get to platform 9¾.

> “Excuse me,” Harry said to the plump woman.
>   “Hullo, dear,” she said. “First time at Hogwarts? Ron’s new, too.” She pointed at the last and youngest of her sons. He was tall, thin, and gangling, with freckles, big hands and feet, and a long nose.
>   “Yes,” said Harry. “The thing is — the thing is, I don’t know
>   how to —”
>   “How to get onto the platform?” she said kindly, and Harry
>   nodded.
>   “Not to worry,” she said. “All you have to do is walk straight at
>   the barrier between platforms nine and ten. Don't stop and don't be
>   scared you’ll crash into it, that’s very important. Best do it at a bit
>   of a run if you’re nervous. Go on, go now before Ron.
>   “Er — OK,” said Harry.” – HP 1 cp.6 p.93